# Strip array of Âº

Tags: php, arrays, character-encoding

I have the following array:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3,38 m
            [1] => 13,30 s
            [2] => 5,41 m
            [3] => ESE
            [4] => 294Âº
            [5] => 32,76 km/h
            [6] => W
            [7] => 266Âº
            [8] => 16,27 ÂºC
            [9] => 12,80 ÂºC
            [10] => 0
        )
```

I'm wanting to clean up the data before adding it to a DB.

This function is almost there but does not remove  the special characters:

```
function cleanUp(&$value,$key)
{
    $cleaner2 = array("km/h"," ","m","s","Âº","ÂºC");
    $value = str_replace($cleaner2, "", $value);
}
array_walk($newArray[0],"cleanUp");
```

I've looked into encoding the array, but I'm not sure what encoding it has now? I could trim the array values, but feel that is rather inelegant.

Any ideas?

**The solution:**
I omitted the charset from the header!

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

This allowed my simple cleanUp function to work as it removed the Â and then matched the following cleaner2 array values:

```
$cleaner2 = array("km/h"," ","m","s","º","ºC","C");
```

Comment: What encoding is your file saved in, and what encoding is it served in?

Comment: Where are those characters coming from to begin with? Looks like you need to *handle encodings correctly*, not clean up the mess after its broken. [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: do you just want numbers and commas?

Comment: I'm using google docs as a scraper which I'm then grabbing as a csv. Yes I just want the numbers, commas and latin letters.

Comment: I would love to share Joel's http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$data = array(
  0 => '3,38 m',
  1 => '13,30 s',
  2 => '5,41 m',
  3 => 'ESE',
  4 => '294Âº',
  5 => '32,76 km/h',
  6 => 'W',
  7 => '266Âº',
  8 => '16,27 ÂºC',
  9 => '12,80 ÂºC',
  10 => 0,
);

$c =  array("km/h"," ","m","s","Âº","ÂºC");
$data = array_map(function($v)use($c) {return mb_replace($c,"",$v);},$data);
var_dump($data);
```

Output

```
array (size=11)
  0 => string '3,38' (length=4)
  1 => string '13,30' (length=5)
  2 => string '5,41' (length=4)
  3 => string 'ESE' (length=3)
  4 => string '294' (length=3)
  5 => string '32,76' (length=5)
  6 => string 'W' (length=1)
  7 => string '266' (length=3)
  8 => string '16,27C' (length=6)
  9 => string '12,80C' (length=6)
  10 => string '0' (length=1)
```

Function Use

```
function mb_replace($search, $replace, $subject, &$count=0) {
    if (!is_array($search) && is_array($replace)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (is_array($subject)) {
        // call mb_replace for each single string in $subject
        foreach ($subject as &$string) {
            $string = &mb_replace($search, $replace, $string, $c);
            $count += $c;
        }
    } elseif (is_array($search)) {
        if (!is_array($replace)) {
            foreach ($search as &$string) {
                $subject = mb_replace($string, $replace, $subject, $c);
                $count += $c;
            }
        } else {
            $n = max(count($search), count($replace));
            while ($n--) {
                $subject = mb_replace(current($search), current($replace), $subject, $c);
                $count += $c;
                next($search);
                next($replace);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $parts = mb_split(preg_quote($search), $subject);
        $count = count($parts)-1;
        $subject = implode($replace, $parts);
    }
    return $subject;
}
```

[Function Credit : Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786018/1226894)

Comment: Thx baba, Your code only works when run on a static array. When I run it against the array generated from the CSV file it still does not remove the ÂºC characters?

Comment: Depends on how you are reading the CSV ....  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13324952/1226894

Comment: @Baba The problem is not multi-byte vs. single byte string function, it's just an encoding mismatch. The replacement simply happens on a raw byte level, the `str_replace` function does not necessarily need to be encoding aware. Only in encodings where byte sequences are ambiguous do you need an encoding aware "mb_replace" function, but I'm not even sure what typically used encoding has this property.

Comment: HI Guys. Baba, you put me on the right track with the link as I noticed that I had set the charset in the header. Setting this to UTF-8 got rid of the Â, following that my simple cleanUp function worked with the addition of ("º","ºC"). thanks for your time - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function __clean( $text )
{
    $buff = implode('[:#:]',$text);
    $buff = str_replace("","UNICODE OF $text",$buff);
    return ($buff); 
}
```